# Symfony2 - Add or remove a field from a subform in nested forms

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a main form which looks like :

```
class ArticleCreateType extends AbstractType
{

  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $user = $options['user'];

    $builder
      ->add('id')
      ->add('date')
      ->add('title');

    if(in_array('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN', $user->getRoles())) {
      $builder->add('articlebody', new ArticleBodyType());
    }
    else {
      // how to add only 'part1' from ArticleBody ??
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

and the subform for the body part is like :

```
class ArticleBodyType extends AbstractType {

  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
      $builder
        ->add('part1', 'textarea', array('required' => false))
        ->add('part2', 'textarea');
  }

  ...
}
```

When the user connected is not the administrator (i.e. instead the comment), I would like to add **ONLY** 'part1' field from ArticleBody in the main form.

I did not succeed in :
- trying to access 'part1' field in ArticleCreateType
- trying to send $options from ArticleCreateType to ArticleBodyType (but I would prefer to do the first way if possible)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd pass the `user` to `ArticleBodyType`, and check the user roles in it..

```
class ArticleCreateType extends AbstractType
{

  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $user = $options['user'];

    $builder
      ->add('id')
      ->add('date')
      ->add('title')
      ->add('articlebody', new ArticleBodyType(), [
          'user' => $user
      ]);
  }

  ...
}

class ArticleBodyType extends AbstractType {

  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

      $user = $options['user'];

      $builder->add('part1', 'textarea', array('required' => false));

      if(in_array('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN', $user->getRoles())) {
        $builder->add('part2', 'textarea');
      } 
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you xurshid29, it works very well in local but on my remote server, I get this kind of error : "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' ..."

Comment: @Antikhippe Short syntax (`[]`) only works with PHP version >=5.4, you better use traditional syntax (`array()`)